# overflow error using datetimes with Pyarrow

Tags: datetime, parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

While randomizing datetimes to test a database, I saved them to parquet using pyarrow.parquets' `write_table()`, then read them back using `read_table()`.

Upon trying to convert to Python datatypes with `to_pydict()`, I recieved the following error:

```
---> 81 from_parquet = pq.read_table('parquet_vs_csv').to_pydict()
     82
     83 '''

pyarrow/table.pxi in pyarrow.lib.Table.to_pydict (/arrow/python/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib.cxx:38283)()

pyarrow/table.pxi in pyarrow.lib.Column.to_pylist (/arrow/python/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib.cxx:31782)()

pyarrow/table.pxi in pyarrow.lib.ChunkedArray.to_pylist (/arrow/python/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib.cxx:30410)()

pyarrow/array.pxi in __iter__ (/arrow/python/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib.cxx:25015)()

pyarrow/scalar.pxi in pyarrow.lib.TimestampValue.as_py (/arrow/python/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib.cxx:21082)()

pyarrow/scalar.pxi in pyarrow.lib.lambda5 (/arrow/python/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib.cxx:7234)()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp.__new__ (pandas/_libs/tslib.c:10051)()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.convert_to_tsobject (pandas/_libs/tslib.c:27665)()

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

I played around, and this happens for datetimes with year larger then 2700 or so (This was at work and this is a larger number, forgot the exact one that was lower).

I'm new to pyarrow, is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem here is that Pandas represents a datetime with nanoseconds since 1970. The time around the year 2700 is simply the limitation that there the number of `nanoseconds-since-1970` exceeds the space that can be represented with an `int64`.

In Arrow, you can represent these dates by using a more granular representation like `milliseconds-since-1970` but on the conversion to Pandas, they are always casted to `nanoseconds-since-1970` and thus this date cannot be represented in Pandas.

Comment: Thanks, 26xx was in fact the "limit" year. Any clues about dates prior to 1918 returning 20-21 mins off?

Comment: I have no idea yet what is causing this but you should watch the following issue which was reported on Github: https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/1446

Comment: I opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1959 to see if there's something we can do here